# How configure redux toolkit rtk query params like ASCII format?

Tags: reactjs, redux, toolkit

I'm trying to pass a string of several words to the parameter. In endpoint, a query is formed with the parameter as "api/pages/search?name=firstWord+secondWord". And I need to get "api/pages/search?name=firstWord%20secondWord"

```
query: (search: string) => {
        // variable search can be multiple words
        return {
          url: `pages/search`,
          params: {
            name: search,
          },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```js
const string = `api/pages/search?name=${encodeURIComponent('firstWord+secondWord')}`;
console.log(string);
```

Comment: I did that and it solved the problem. But the original goal was to transfer this value through the parameter "param" in query, and not to form the query string "manually"